# How to define and act by an element of $\operatorname{PSL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ in Sage

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sagemath

I've defined a projective variety in Sage, and I would now like to act on that by matrices in $\operatorname{PSL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create an element of $\operatorname{PSL}_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ as a matrix, rather than as a permutation. My code for constructing the variety is below:

```
P.<a,b,c> = ProjectiveSpace(2, GF(11)) 
V = P3.subscheme([a^2 + b^2 - c^2])
```

I've figured out that I can construct $\operatorname{PSL}_3(\mathbb{F}_{11})$ as a permutation group with

```
G = PSL(3,11)
```

What I have, however, are particular matrices in $\operatorname{PSL}_3(\mathbb{F}_{11})$ that I would like to have act on the points in my variety `V`. Is there any way I can construct PSL as a matrix group, or convert my matrices to elements in `G` and have them act on the points of `V`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the finite projective linear groups comes from GAP, where they’re realized as permutations only. You can either circumvent the problem and work with the action of $\mathrm {SL}_3(\mathbb{F}_{11})$, or create your own $\mathrm{PSL}_n$ with matrices, just like it is done [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/62674/how-do-the-points-that-pgl-acts-on-correspond-to-the-elements-of-projectivespace/).

Comment: Thanks! That link is really helpful since I'm new to Sage. I'll also comment here in case anyone else looks at this --- if you're interested primarily in looking at the action of some matrices, you can implement that by creating a homomorphism of projective schemes. This is in the "Morphisms on projective schemes" section of the documentation.